# Flying Machines

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I've seen multiple tutorials about Flying Machines but I can never understand the mechanics behind them. How does it work? How do I exactly make one to fit my redstone creation?

Comment: Bedrock Edition? oh, dear. The flying machines for BE are 90% overcoming BE problems, 10% doing what Java flying machines do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to know how slime and honey blocks work. They both stick with any block beside, apart from obsidian, bedrock, glazed terracotta, or even regular piston arms (if we talk about vanilla experience), but they won't touch each other, so it's useful for many redstone machines.

Next up, observers. If an observer finds an updated block in front of its face, it activates, giving it a redstone pulse at the other side, which then can activate the piston in front of the observer's back.

You can make a flying machine with a piston facing somewhere, and slime/honey blocks in front of it, also, observers at their backs facing at them. Then a similar one 1-block-higher than the original, facing at the opposite direction, but instead using a sticky piston.

Comment: ...and it's a 1-directional machine. You want anything more fancy (or actually useful) you face an uphill battle.

Comment: Yeah, it acts very different from Java machines, thanks to the sticky piston mechanics.